# mapping one environment variable to another in elasticbeanstalk settings

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I map one environment variable to another in aws elasticbeanstalk configuration.  I need to map RDS_HOSTNAME to DATABASE_HOST since that's what my app is expecting.

I tried setting DATABASE_HOST = $RDS_HOSTNAME but I think that just sets it as the literal string "$RDS_HOSTNAME"

Comment: that's a bad practice, it's a symptom that your code needs refactoring and probably it's impossible to achieve by just using EB settings

Comment: unfortunately there's no way around it since our production environment is amazon and our test environment is codeship and they both have hard coded environment variable names.  I can configure environment variable names by environment but that seems a bit kludgy as well and an over engineered solution